# Как использовать метод set() в arraylist с несколькими переменными в объекте?

Tags: java, arraylist

Имеется класс-конструктор

```
public class Players {
    String name;
    int points;
    public Players(String nam, int point){
        this.name = nam;
        this.points = point;
    }
```

В другом классе объявлен ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Players> playersList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Как я могу заменить переменную points для определенного объекта в этом arraylist?

Comment: где тут собственно arraylist?

Comment: `playersList.get(i).points = newPoints;`